# Will Facebook suggest my Facebook friends to my Facebook acquaintances?

Tags: facebook, facebook-privacy

I have set my Facebook friends list to be private, so that, supposedly, only I can see who my Facebook friends are.

However, one of my FB friends (let's call him "A") has also set his list to be private and, as it is obvious, I can only see in his FB friends list people who are also my FB friends. In other words, only mutual friends are visible to me. But despite this, I got a FB suggestion to add a person "B" as a friend and in the suggestion it says "B" is a friend of my friend "A". The problem is that I should not be able to see that "B" is a friend of "A" anywhere on FB. (Because "B" is obviously not one of my FB friends.)

So basically setting your FB friends list to private doesn't work. I don't want any of my FB friends to be suggested to any of my other FB friends. Is there any way this can be done?

I thought this: if I add one of my FB friends to my "acquaintances" list, will any of my FB "friends" still be suggested to him/her?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, what’s happening is that friend “B” has a public friend list. Then there’s nothing stopping you from knowing that “A” and “B” are friends (through “B”’s friend list), even though “A” has a private friends list.

As far as I’m aware, *Acquaintances* is simply an access level. As far as friend suggestions go, that wouldn’t have any effect.